# How do I fix 11.10 GUI?

Tags: 11.10, nvidia, multiple-monitors, gui

This happens in both gnome and Ubuntu.  I can log in just fine.  But nothing loads.  All I see is my background.  This happend after I was trying to get my dual screens configured correctly.

Comment: What steps did you take to configure your dual screen application? Can you please add that to the question?

Comment: Sounds like Unity died. Can you try this? -http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears

Answer (score 1):

As a temporary solution, try creating a new user account and logging in from there, or log in to a Guest session. Those problems are usually associated with broken configuration files in your home folder, so a new user account should load just fine.

Comment: If I logon with Guest all I get is black menu bar, with basic menu file, edit, etc.  Is unity busted?

Comment: I created a new user and logged in.  Both my screens are working properly now, but nothing loads but the background.  I can only get to the command line by pressing ctrl+alt+f2.

Comment: Switching to Gnome and logging in with new user I can get to the system settings I get and error trying to access display "Could not get Screen Information RANDR extension is not present

Comment: Then it sounds like your system settings were messed up. Switching the user won't help with that. When you said you were trying to get your dual screens configured did you mean that you were installing and removing packages from the system? Did you use the Package Manager or apt-get? Or were you editing system files like xorg.conf?